# Utilizing Date Time Lookup in AMPScript on Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, campaign

I'm trying to run an AMPScript in my emails where I'll be able to link in some meta data on my subscribers.

I'd like to utilize when they signed up as a point to discern if the subscriber is new, old, or very old.

Here's the script that I wrote, but it is not accepted.

```
 VAR @Registrationdate

 SET @Registrationdate = [Registration Date]

  VAR @membertag

 IF @Registrationdate < 'NOW()-60' THEN SET   
  @membertag = 'very-old'

 ELSEIF @Registrationdate < 'NOW()-30' THEN SET   
  @membertag = 'old'

 ELSE SET
  @membertag = 'new'

 ENDIF
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Shmuel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes around `NOW()-60` and `NOW()-30` are causing that code to be read as a text string.

The [DateAdd()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DateAdd.htm) AMPscript function can be used to calculate your dates, by using negative numeric values to subtract the days from the current date.

```
%%[

VAR @Registrationdate, @membertag
set @Registrationdate = [Registration Date]

IF @Registrationdate < DateAdd(NOW(), '-60','D') THEN 
  set @membertag = 'very-old'
ELSEIF @Registrationdate < DateAdd(NOW(), '-30','D') THEN
  set @membertag = 'old'
ELSE 
  set @membertag = 'new'
ENDIF 

]%%
```

If any of the dates are saved as strings, then the [DateParse()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DateParse.htm) function should be utilized to ensure a date object is being evaluated, instead of just a string.